# How can I place a button (TouchableHighlight) or equivalent inside a Text component in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to place a button inside a text component, but I receive an error "Nesting of  within  is not currently supported."  When I move my "TouchableHighlight" component outside the  component, it creates an issue where I receive a warning, "Cannot update during an existing state transition.."

I'm looking for a workaround or advice on how to approach.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View
} from 'react-native'

class TakeQuiz extends React.Component {

  state = {
    cardIndex : 0,
    currentCardId : "",
    correctAnswers : 0,
    incorrectAnswers : 0,
    showAnswer: false
  }

toggleAnswer(){
  this.setState( () => ({
    showAnswer : !this.state.showAnswer})
  )
}

recordScore(userAnswer, correctAnswer){
  if(userAnswer == correctAnswer){
    this.setState( () => {
      correctAnswers : this.state.correctAnswers +1
    })
  }

  this.setState( () => ({
    cardIndex : this.state.cardIndex +1
  }))
}

currentQuestion(){
  return
}

render() {

const { dispatch, navigation } = this.props;

const deckId = navigation.getParam('deck')
let deck = this.props.deck[deckId];
let deckName = Object.values(deckId);
let cards = Object.keys(deck)
const br = `\n`;

return (
<ScrollView>
<Text>

{cards.map( (card) =>{
  return (

  <Text key={card} id={card}>

  {this.setState( () => {
    currentCardId : card
  })}

  {
    (cards[this.state.cardIndex] == card)
    ? <Text>{br}{br}Card ID: {card} {br}</Text>
    : <Text></Text>
  }


  {
    (cards[this.state.cardIndex] == card)
    ? <Text style={styles.question}>{deck[card].question}</Text>
    : <Text></Text>
  }

  {
    (cards[this.state.cardIndex] == card)
    ? this.state.showAnswer && <Text style={styles.answer}>{br}{deck[card].answer}{br}Correct Answers: {this.state.correctAnswers}</Text>
    : <Text></Text>
  }

  {br}{br}
  </Text>
)
})
}

</Text>


<TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.recordScore("yes", this.state.currentCardId)}>
        <Text style={styles.btn}>Yes</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
      <Text>{br}{br}</Text>
<TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.recordScore("no", this.state.currentCardId)}>
        <Text style={styles.btn}>No</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
      <Text>{br}{br}</Text>
<TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.toggleAnswer()}>
        <Text style={styles.btn}>Show Answer</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>


</ScrollView>

  )
}
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  btn: {
    backgroundColor : '#E53224',
    color : '#ffffff',
    textAlign : 'center',
    padding: 10,
    paddingLeft : 80,
    paddingRight: 80,
    justifyContent : 'center',
    alignItems : 'center',
    borderRadius : 5,
  },

  btnText : {
    color : '#ffff'
  },

  question : {
    fontSize : 24
  },

  answer : {
    fontSize : 18,
    color : "#778899"
  }

})

const mapStateToProps = (state, deckId) => {
  return {
      deck : state.flashcards.decks
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TakeQuiz);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Text` components can only contain string values. An error occurs when you insert another object value.

Comment: I realized what I was trying to do can't be done, and refactored the code to better use State to update the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Also Text components accepts onPress.
Another option is to have a View with nested TouchableHighlights with Texts inside.